# How do you decompress a gz file?

Tags: windows, gzip, mobaxterm

Hi I'm trying to open gz files on my computer (windows 10) in the terminal (MobaXterm) could some one guide me on how to do it thank you.

I've tried using gunzip file.gz and gzip -d file.gz but they don't seem to work

Comment: what is the output of `file file.gz`?

Comment: it gives me "gzip compressed data"

Comment: that confrms the file type, so gunzip should be able to unzip it. if gunzip cannot unzip it, maybe it is truncated or it got corrupted by an FTP in text mode for instance?

Comment: i ran gunzip file.gz and it runs fine but I'm trying to open it up in IGV but it still says the file is zipped. How do I know if the file is truncated or got corrupted.

Comment: after gunzip ran, you can use the `file ` command on the unpacked file to see what file type it is. is it possible it got zipped twice?

Comment: It appears that it did get zipped twice how am I able to undue that?

Comment: unzip it twice, you might have to rename it in between to give it the correct extension.